# How to get contact id using email address with infusionsoft gem

Tags: rubygems, infusionsoft

Is there a way to pull a contact's id from infusionsoft using the infusionsoft gem if I have the contact email?

Answer (score 0):

```
selected_fields = %w(:id)
results = Infusionsoft.contact_find_by_email("johndoe@example.com", selected_fields)
```

The results from this API call would be:

```
[{"id" => "9999"}]
```

See https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#contact-search-for-a-contact-by-an-email-address